# MsgBox is not displaying the right value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, triggers, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I have a `DropDownList`, and when `SelectedIndex` is changed any event is triggered.

I'm  putting on it for exemple msgbox, but it's not working.

What's the problem ?

```
EDIT;
```

now that's working after doing `AutoPostBack = True`.
I did this, but i't giving me always '0' as result

```
Protected Sub VD_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
MsgBox VD.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you show a little more code, namely where you're creating the DropDownList control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have AutoPostBack = True and hook up an event to OnSelectedIndexChanged.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the `AutoPostBack` value on your control to `true` ?